# Как отловить появление редактора в DOM?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

В событии `init` редактора TinyMCE проверяю, появилась ли его панель инструментов на странице и выясняю, что она появляется позже возникновения этого события:

```
editor.on('init', function(editor) {
    alert(jQuery('.mce-panel').length);
});
```

Эта функция выводит на экран `0`. Как можно отловить появление редактора в коде страницы, чтобы внутри этой функции выполнить над его панелью инструментов определенные действия?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему вам нужен 'postRender' ивент: [дока](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onPostRender)

С этим вариантом у меня в алерте не ноль:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.on('postRender', function (e) {
            alert(jQuery('.mce-panel').length);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: делаю так: `editor.on('postRender', function(editor) {` и все равно выводит `0`. В коде страницы видно, как разметка редактора и панели инструментов появляется после того, как произошло это событие...

Comment: а попробуйте init_instance_callback - https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#init_instance_callback

Comment: и все равно та же проблема.(

Comment: так, ну я не поленился попробовать и у меня не ноль... сейчас впишу в ответ свой вариант

Comment: похоже, дело в `inline: true`. Ваш вариант работает, и у себя, если отключаю inline-редактирование, добиваюсь правильной работы. Но inline отключать не хотелось бы... Интересно, это баг такой?

Comment: на англиском стаке гуглится интересный хинт с ручным фаером фокус-ивента: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438428/creating-a-tinymce-inline-editor-and-making-it-visible-from-a-button

Comment: я так понимаю, идея в том, чтобы дать фокус редактору, после чего появится панель инструментов? Она так и продолжает появляться не раньше, чем завершится выполнение всех выполняющихся функций.

Comment: чесно, я бы вообще наверное свою проверку навесил через сет-интервал с выходом из него при успешной однократной отработке нужного кода, раз уж встроенные ивенты не помогают

Comment: да, видимо, так и придется делать. Спасибо за ответ.